# In redis,how to get the keys descending order based on insertion order?

Tags: caching, redis, feed

I am implementing a feed for a social network in that newly uploaded post should be served first and so on.I use hashes of posts as keys and posts as values.I need the posts in "newest first order".How to do it?
My idea is

1. Store the post and timestamp with hash as a key
2. Get all keys and timestamps
3. Sort the timestamps in descending order
4. Then use the respective keys to get th latest images

Question1:But this approach is not good.How to do it ?
EDIT:Question2:Please tell me what algorithm you use to serve feed.If feed is common for all users based on "newest-first",how to implement it?
This is my first time in backend.Please if the question is dumb.
Thanks.

Comment: Keep a sorted set by timestamp of the posts, where the score is a timestamp and the value is the post id. Then read the keys in whatever order you want.

Comment: Thank you!.I am gonna use this for feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three options for you:

Use a sorted set, using the timestamp as score, and the post-hash as value. The post-hash is also the key in a hash where the actual posts are stored. Commands involved: ZADD, HSET, ZREVRANGEBYSCORE, HGET.

Use a sorted set, using the timestamp as score, and the post with metadata as value. Make sure "post with metadata" is unique, you can include the timestamp and user to achieve this. This will have better performance, but makes it a bit harder if you have to find a specific post. Commands involved: ZADD, ZREVRANGEBYSCORE, ZRANGEBYSCORE.

Use Redis Streams. If you want a uniform insert order independent of client time, Redis can set the timestamp for you. However, stream entries cannot be modified, so either users cannot edit posts, or whenever they edit the post is brought up as new. Commands involved: XADD, XREVRANGE, XDEL.

See:

- [Redis Commands](https://redis.io/commands)
- [Introduction to Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

Comment: Another option is to use incremental post ids, and then use lexical ranges in a sorted set. For a lot of things they are better than score based indexing